# MS Graph Create open extension call with Json object

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create events using MS Graph. We are using json objects with the call as in this example

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", msBearerToken);
    var callJson = new
                   {
                       Subject = EventSummery.Title,
                       Body = new
                       {
                           ContentType = BodyType.Html.ToString(),
                           Content = EventSummery.Description
                       },
                       Start = new
                       {
                           DateTime = EventSummery.StartDateUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
                           TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time"
                       },
                       End = new
                       {
                           DateTime = EventSummery.EndDateUTC.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"),
                           TimeZone = "GMT Standard Time"
                       }
                    };
```

I need to add an open extension however the documentation I need to add this attribute

```
"extensions": [
{
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
    "extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Referral",
    "companyName": "Wingtip Toys",
    "expirationDate": "2015-12-30T11:00:00.000Z",
    "dealValue": 10000
}]
```

however @odata.type throws an error if I put it in this form:

```
Extensions = new
             {
                  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
                  "extensionName": "Com.Contoso.Referral",
                  "companyName": "Wingtip Toys",
                  "expirationDate": "2015-12-30T11:00:00.000Z",
                  "dealValue": 10000
             }
```

What am I missing how can I make this call successfully?

Comment: What exception does it throw? Could you share the whole code how do you send data with using httpClient? Do first code section is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you cannot create anonymous object with property that has a special character at the beginning.

Only way is to create a class with properties that have `JsonPropertyName` attribute and then use json serializer.

```
public class OpenTypeExtension
{
    [JsonPropertyName("@odata.type")]
    public string ODataType { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("extensionName")]
    public string ExtensionName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("companyName")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("expirationDate")]
    public string ExpirationDate{ get; set; }    

    [JsonPropertyName("dealValue")]
    public string DealValue{ get; set; }  

    public OpenTypeExtension()
    {
        ODataType = "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension";
    }
}
```